# Google Chrome Extension Command Hotkeys

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that recognizes when I press Ctrl+Shift+X. I am using the commands API and I put it in my manifest. Then, in my background page, I get the command and try to automatically press a button on a page. For some reason, it does not work and I'm not getting an error. Can you guys help me? Thanks!
I am using my program on this website:
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/b82ba9vpq/jx7qm1hsc
When I am not using commands, it works perfectly fine
Manifest:

```
    {
  "manifest_version":2,

  "name": "Hotkey",
  "description": "Press buttons on keyboard to activate hotkeys.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "commands":{
     "doo":{
    "suggested_key":{
    "default":"Ctrl+Shift+X",
        "mac":"Command+Shift+X"
        },
    "description":"Fast"
     }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                file: "injector.js"
            });
});
```

injector.js

```
  function goToActivityTab() {
        var activityTab = document.getElementsByName("commit")[0];

    activityTab.click();
    sleepFor(100);
    var addToCart=document.getElementsByClassName("button checkout")[0];
    addToCart.click();
}

goToActivityTab();
function sleepFor( sleepDuration ){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ } 
}
```

Comment: `sleepFor` doesn't sleep, it simply blocks JS engine, and nothing can be processed while it's blocked on the page. Look for tutorials/examples on using setTimeout.

Comment: Also, instead of `.click()` try sending DOM events: addToCart.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))

Comment: bbut my commands api works fine right?

Comment: Wait, when I run my injector.js on a button click instead of commands, it works perfectly fine